# How to count number of digits?

Tags: scheme, racket

> 1. `(CountDigits n)` takes a positive integer `n`, and returns the number of digits it contains. e.g.,
>
>    ```
>    (CountDigits 1) → 1
>    (CountDigits 10) → 2
>    (CountDigits 100) → 3
>    (CountDigits 1000) → 4
>    (CountDigits 65536) → 5
>    ```

I think I'm supposed to use the remainder of the number and something else but other then that im really lost. what i tried first was dividing the number by 10 then seeing if the number was less then 1. if it was then it has 1 digit. if it doesnt then divide by 100 and so on and so forth. but im not really sure how to extend that to any number so i scrapped that idea

(define (num-digits number digit)
  (if (= number digit 0)
      1

Comment: One of the reasons for closing questions on Stack Overflow is that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  What have you tried so far?  If you're not comfortable writing code yet, how would you do tihs by hand?  How would you, step by step, determine how many digits there are in, say, "32178"?

Comment: I bet there are more constraints on the ways that you can solve this, too.  For instance, Racket includes some functions for converting numbers to strings, such as [`number->string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28part._.Number--.String_.Conversions%29).  You can take the length of a string with `string-length`.  This means that `(string-length (number->string 234678))` returns `6`.  Does this work for you?

Comment: Ah, I see an update to the question.  OK, so you want to use some arithmetic operations… If I give you a number with _x_ digits, what operation can you do to get a number with _x-1_ digits?  Similarly, what can you do to check whether a number has just one digit?  (We can assume, I think, that we're dealing only with positive numbers.)

Comment: No i have to work it out recursively, which is what im having trouble with

Comment: you could divide by 10. for a single digit we could see if the division of 10 and the number is less than 1.

Comment: I figured as much, but I wanted to make sure that it got into the question. :) Take a look my latest comment.

Comment: OK, so dividing by 10 will give a number with one less digit.  What about checking whether a number has only one digit?

Comment: for a single digit we could see if the division of 10 and the number is less than 1. i wrote the function on top for the case of zero also

Comment: Right, a number less than 10 requires only one digit.  Now I'm ready to move to the answer…

Comment: thanks! I got it. but can you just explain verbally whats happening in the function?

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled across this and had to provide the log-based answer:

```
(define (length n)
    (+ 1 (floor (/ (log n) (log 10))))
)
```

Edit for clarity: This is an O(1) solution that doesn't use recursion. For example, given

```
(define (fact n)
  (cond
    [(= n 1) 1]
    [else (* n (fact (- n 1)))]
  )
)

(define (length n)
  (+ 1 (floor (/ (log n) (log 10))))
)
```

Running (time (length (fact 10000))) produces

```
cpu time: 78 real time: 79 gc time: 47
35660.0
```

Indicating that 10000! produces an answer consisting of 35660 digits.

Comment: This should be `round`, not `floor`. `(define (count-whole-digits x) (add1 (round (/ (log (abs x)) (log 10)))))` as shown by `(map count-whole-digits (list 1 10 1e2 1e3 1e4 1e5 1e6))`

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion in the comments, we figured out how to take a number *n* with *x* digits and to get a number with *x-1* digits:  divide by 10 (using integer division, i.e., we ignore the remainder).  We can check whether a number only has one digit by checking whether it's less than 10.  Now we just need a way to express the total number of digits in a number as a (recursive) function.  There are two cases:

1. (base case) a number *n* less than 10 has 1 digit.  So CountDigits(*n*) = 1.
2. (recursive case) a number *n* greater than 10 has CountDigits(*n*) = 1+CountDigits(*n/10*).

Now it's just  a matter of coding this up.  This sounds like homework, so I don't want to give everything away.  You'll still need to figure out how to write the condition "*n* < 10" in Scheme, as well as "*n*/10" (just the quotient part), but the general structure is:

```
(define (CountDigits n)                       ; 1
  (if [n is less than 10]                     ; 2
      1                                       ; 3
      (+ 1 (CountDigits [n divided by 10])))) ; 4
```

An explanation of those lines, one at a time:

1. `(define (CountDigits n)` begins the definition of a function called `CountDigits` that's called like `(CountDigits n)`.
2. In Racket, `if` is used to evaluate one expression, called the test, or the condition, and then to evaluate and return the value of one of the two remaining expressions.  `(if test X Y)` evaluates `test`, and if `test` produces **true**, then `X` is evaluated and the result is returned, but otherwise `Y` is evaluated and the result is returned.
3. `1` is the value that you want to return when *n* is less than 10 (the base case above).
4. 1+CountDigits(n/10) is the value that you want to return otherwise, and in Racket (and Scheme, and Lisp in general) it's written as `(+ 1 (CountDigits [n divided by 10]))`.

It will be a good idea to familiarize with the style of the Racket documentation, so I will point you to the appropriate chapter: [3.2.2 Generic Numerics](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html).  The functions you'll need should be in there, and the documentation should provide enough examples for you to figure out how to write the missing bits.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but for future reference to anyone who finds this personally I'd write it like this:

```
(define (count-digits n acc)
  (if (< n 10)
    (+ acc 1)
    (count-digits (/ n 10) (+ acc 1))))
```

The difference being that this one is tail-recursive and will essentially be equivalent to an iterative function(and internally Racket's iterative forms actually exploit this fact.)

Using trace illustrates the difference:

```
(count-digits-taylor 5000000)
>(count-digits-taylor 5000000)
> (count-digits-taylor 500000) 
> >(count-digits-taylor 50000)
> > (count-digits-taylor 5000)
> > >(count-digits-taylor 500)
> > > (count-digits-taylor 50)
> > > >(count-digits-taylor 5)
< < < <1
< < < 2
< < <3
< < 4
< <5
< 6
<7
7

(count-digits 5000000 0)
>(count-digits 5000000 0)
>(count-digits 500000 1)
>(count-digits 50000 2)
>(count-digits 5000 3)
>(count-digits 500 4)
>(count-digits 50 5)
>(count-digits 5 6)
<7
7
```

For this exercise this doesn't matter much, but it's a good style to learn. And of course since the original post asks for a function called CountDigits which only takes one argument (n) you'd just add:

```
(define (CountDigits n) 
  (count-digits n 0))
```