# Make a program that determines the average of its digits from a number

Tags: racket

I must make a program that averages the digits of a number, but it is impossible for me, especially the module of a division (remainder).

What I can do?

```
(define (digitos number)
  (cond
  [(and (>= number 1) (< number 11)) 1]
  [else (+ 1 (digitos (/ number 10)))]))

(define (modulo_ n m)
  (cond
    [(real? n) (- n (* (floor (/ n m)) m))]
    [else (remainder n m)]))

(define (sumatoria number)
  (cond
    [(equal? number 0) 0]
    [else (+ (modulo_ number 10) (sumatoria (/ number 10)))]))

(define (promedio number)
  (/ (sumatoria number) (digitos number)))

;(promedio 40) ;3
```

Comment: What do you really want? Please write some input and output example.

Comment: it was the wrong code, I already put what it was.

Comment: sorry again, that would give 2, because 4 + 0 = 4/2 then 2

Answer (score 0):

update:
your question is repeated
[How to count number of digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530112/how-to-count-number-of-digits?rq=1)
[Count digits in list Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019105/count-digits-in-list-racket)
[Return the sum of odd digits of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229379/return-the-sum-of-odd-digits-of-a-number)
[Convert number to list of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014453/convert-number-to-list-of-digits)

```
; only consider nature number 0,1,2,3,...
; if you want input Decimal use number->string

(define (cut-right-digit n)
  (/ (- n (remainder n 10)) 10))

(define (sum-each-digit n result)
  (cond
    [(<= 0 n 9)
     (+ result n)]
    [else 
     (sum-each-digit (cut-right-digit n) (+ result (remainder n 10)))]))

(define (digits n result)
  (cond
    [(<= 0 n 9)
     result]
    [else
     (digits (cut-right-digit n) (+ 1 result))]))

(define (avg-digits n)
  (/ (sum-each-digit n 0) (digits n 1)))

;;; TEST

(avg-digits 0) ; 0
(avg-digits 1) ; 1
(avg-digits 11111) ; 1
(avg-digits 10203040506789) ; (/ 55 14)
(avg-digits 101001) ; 1/2
```